# Overloading operator >> and << so that it accepts user-defined object

Tags: c++, stream, overloading

I've got an object (of class myObj) that contains multiple strings (a string pointer). I want to overload the >>operator so that I can read in multiple strings at a time.

This overloaded operator functions accept statements like:

cin >> str;

cout << str;

The only problem is that when I fill in a series of strings, it seems that only the first string gets correctly processed in the stream.

To insert:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &is, myObj &obj)
{
    std::string line;

    while (true)
    {
        std::getline(is, line);
        if (not is)
            break;
        obj.add(line);
        is >> line;
    }

    return is; 
}
```

To extract

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, myObj const &obj)
{
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx != obj.size(); ++idx) 
        os << obj[idx];
    return os;
}
```

The code compiles fine but when I cout the object only the first string is printed and the other strings are omitted.

So when I provide cin with:

```
Hi
Stack
Exchange
```

only Hi will be displayed.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

P.S I am new to Stack Exchange and I am working hard to formulate the problems as best as I can :)

Comment: Why doing `std::getline` and `is >> line` in the loop? This will extract data twice, thus missing one every two line

Comment: Thanks! That actually solved it! I looked completely over it =/

Comment: Why not `while (std::getline(is, line)) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will work like that:

```
std::getline(is, line);
```

Extracts and stores "Hi" in `line`, extracts the newline

```
obj.add(line);
```

Adds "Hi" to `obj`

```
is >> line;
```

Extracts and stores "Stack" in `line`, does not extracts the following newline

```
std::getline(is, line);
```

Extracts and stores an empty string in `line`, because next read char is a newline

```
obj.add(line);
```

Adds empty string "" to `obj`

```
is >> line;
```

Extracts and stores "Exchange" in `line`

```
std::getline(is, line);
```

Extracts nothing (end of input stream)

```
if (not is)
    break;
```

Then the stream is at end, your loop exits.

**Conclusion : you stored only Hi and an empty string**

Answer (score 1):

`is >> line` puts a leading newline in the stream which is being read by `std::getline()` during the following loop. Because `std::getline()` stops input when it finds a newline, this reads an empty string into `line` and thus the stream is put into an error state which the loop responds to by breaking out of it.

There doesn't seem to be a need for that last read. You can remove it.

Also, this is a more idiomatic way to loop with input. This way you don't have to check the state of the stream within the loop body:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(is, line); )
{
    obj.add(line);
}
```

And since there's only one token per line, you can use a formmatted extractor:

```
for (std::string word; is >> word; )
{
    obj.add(word);
}
```

Comment: Are these for-loop C++14? I haven't seen that before.. Can you explain it? How could it terminate looping?

Comment: I adapted this implementation and it compiled using C++11, so it has been a feature that existed before C++14.

Comment: @0x382fd442 This is not a special for loop. All three statements to a for loop are optional, first of all. The first statement is for variable declarations, the second is the condition whereby the loop will stop, and the third is the statement to run at the end of the loop. Functions like `std::getline()` and `operator>>()` return a reference to the stream that have an `operator bool()` method that returns a boolean indicating success or failure.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Well I have tried this but it seems not working well when I pass `cin` into the loop. It does not terminate it when I type <enter> only.

Comment: @0x382fd442 Is the code the same as what's shown here? It might be because `operator>>()` discards leading whitespace. Newline is a whitespace character.

Comment: @0x499602D2 well you are right! It works for general istream but not for `cin`.

Comment: The for loop would even be valid in c (except the use of classes), the second statement (test) just doing also the job of the third (incrementation). However in this case it is much more conventionnal to use a while loop, and more conventionnal means more readable by a majority of people. `std::string line; while(std::getline(is, line))...`

Comment: @galinette I don't perfer the single while loop as it exposes the identifier `line` into the outer scope. It's better to keep it within its own block where its needed.